# UnicodeDecodeError or Undecipherible results

Tags: python

I've taken over a project for university and am getting to grips with the existing code base. I am encountering an error, as in the title, where I am getting a UnicodeDecodeError when I attempt to run the code. Essentially, the software parses documents for citations and then exports and analyses them, storing them in a JSON and classifying them as academic or non-academic based on keywords.

I have (somewhat?) worked on the issue, where putting "encoding = ''" in the with open() call will fix it - but only with codecs other than utf-8, such as latin1. Also putting "errors = 'ignore'" in this with open() call fixes it. Based on other lines of code, I am sure the codec used is utf-8. I am stumped as to why I am running into this issue and am not quite sure on where to begin to fix it (firstly, having not written the code myself and secondly, I am new to Python having self-taught it for this project).

The error I was previously getting is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/path/GUIFrontend.py", line 50, in filepath_submitted
    results = return_dict_of_results(filepath)
  File "C:/path/GUIFrontend.py", line 131, in return_dict_of_results
    results_array = loader_text.return_citation_array()
  File "C:\path\DataLoaders\CitationLoaderTxt.py", line 23, in return_citation_array
    for string in self.__nonblank_lines__(file):
  File "C:\path\DataLoaders\CitationLoaderTxt.py", line 65, in __nonblank_lines__
    for l in file:
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 72: invalid start byte
```

The issue I then run into, when I get the code working, is undecipherable results, such as the below, when I use either of the above to actually get the code running.

```
{"C:/Users/myname/Downloads/paper-8641.pdf": [{"__class__": "CitationObj", "__module__": "Citations.CitationObj", "title": "\u2020\u2021L\u017e|}\u00fa\u0002Ii8\u203arJUb\u00a3\u001b7\u00fa\u0006\u00a2\u203a\u2021\u203a\u00e8\u00e6\u00db7\u00ef\u00ee\u00de|\u00f1\u00be\u00cco\u0160\u00b0\u00cc\u00b2\u00e4\u00e6\u00ee\u00fe&\u00ceu\u00a8\u00b3\u00fc&/\u00f30/\u00d2\u203a\u00bb\u00e3\u00cd?\u0192\u00f7\u00b7E\u0014\u201e\u00b7{\u2022F\u00c1\u00f7\u00d5`;\u0006\u00ab\u00ee\u00c8\u00c0\u00d7B\u00fb0\u00ce\u00b4\u00b7\u00ff\u00ba\u00fb\u00e3M\u2018\u2021I\u2019\u00dcDa\u201dH'?\u00ab,!\u00d2>", "author": [], "journal": "", "id": "C:/Users/myname/Downloads/paper-8641.pdf", "classification": "Academic"}
```

Below are the scripts from where the errors stem:

```py
# Loader dedicated to loading text files and extracting the info into our given citation object

import json
import re
from DataLoaders import CitationLoaderBase
from Citations.CitationObj import CitationObj


class CitationLoaderTxt(CitationLoaderBase.CitationLoaderBase):
    # Path: path to the text file you are looking to extract citations from
    # AnalyzedFiles: Array containing the info of files that have already been analyzed
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.regex = "\d*.(.*)\"(.*)\"(.*)|\d*.(.*)"
        self.path = path
        self.analyzedFiles = []

    # Loads file from instance variable and runs through the file returning all
    # matches to the regex supplied as a instance variable as a array
    def return_citation_array(self):
        if self.__has_file_been_read__():
            print("Finding matches to " + self.regex + " in file at " + self.path + " to return as array")
            list_of_citations = []
            with open(self.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                for string in self.__nonblank_lines__(file):
                    match = re.search(self.regex, string)
                    if match.group(1) is None:
                        list_of_citations.append(CitationObj(match.group(4), [], "", self.path))
                    else:
                        list_of_authors = [match.group(1)]
                        list_of_citations.append(CitationObj(match.group(2), list_of_authors, match.group(3), self.path))
            self.analyzedFiles.append(self.path)
            return list_of_citations
        else:
            print("File already analyzed")

    def return_citation_dictionary(self):
        if self.__has_file_been_read__():
            print("Finding matches to " + self.regex + " in file at " + self.path + " to return as dictionary")
            list_of_citations = []
            with open(self.path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                for string in self.__nonblank_lines__(file):
                    match = re.search(self.regex, string)
                    if match.group(1) is None:
                        list_of_citations.append(CitationObj(match.group(4), [], "", self.path))
                        self.analyzedFiles.append(self.path)
                    else:
                        list_of_authors = [match.group(1)]
                        list_of_citations.append(CitationObj(match.group(2), list_of_authors, match.group(3), self.path))
                        self.analyzedFiles.append(self.path)
            citation_dict = {"Citations" : list_of_citations}
            self.analyzedFiles.append(self.path)
            return citation_dict
        else:
            print("File already analyzed")


    def change_file(self, new_file_path):
        self.path = new_file_path

    # Clears the analyzed files from the analyzedFiles list
    def clear_analyzed_files(self):
        self.analyzedFiles = []

    # removes all blank lines from the input file to help preserve ordering
    def __nonblank_lines__(self, file):
        for l in file:
            line = l.rstrip()
            if line:
                yield line

    # Determines if the file has already been analyzed and returns a boolean to that effect
    def __has_file_been_read__(self):
        if len(self.analyzedFiles) > 0:
            for file in self.analyzedFiles:
                if self.path == file:
                    return False
        return True
```

```py
#Loader for PDF files, extracting info from the text of academic papers,
# does however break liskov substitution principle due to addition of a additional parameter for userinput
from Citations.CitationObj import CitationObj
from DataLoaders.CitationLoaderBase import CitationLoaderBase
import re
import textract
import json


class CitationLoaderPDF(CitationLoaderBase):
    # filePath: path to the PDF file you are looking to extract citations from
    # regexPath: path for the user defined file to define the regexs
    # AnalyzedFiles: Array containing the info of files that have already been analyzed
    def __init__(self, filepath, regexpath):
        self.filePath = filepath
        self.regexPath = regexpath
        self.analyzedFiles = []

    def return_citation_array(self):
        if self.__has_file_been_read__():
            list_of_citation_objects = []
            pdf_text = self.__get_pdf_text__()
            citation_regex = self.__get_citation_regex__()
            citation_data = re.findall(citation_regex, pdf_text)
            for citation in citation_data:
                list_of_citation_objects.append(CitationObj(citation[1], citation[0], citation[2], self.filePath))
            self.analyzedFiles.append(self.filePath)
            return list_of_citation_objects
        else:
            print("File already analyzed")

    def return_citation_dictionary(self):
        if self.__has_file_been_read__():
            list_of_citation_objects = []
            pdf_text = self.__get_pdf_text__()
            citation_regex = self.__get_citation_regex__()
            citation_data = re.findall(citation_regex, pdf_text)
            for citation in citation_data:
                list_of_citation_objects.append(CitationObj(citation[1], citation[0], citation[2], self.filePath))
            citation_dict = {"Citations": list_of_citation_objects}
            self.analyzedFiles.append(self.filePath)
            return citation_dict
        else:
            print("File already analyzed")

    # Returns a dictionary of all terms the user has defined in the users config file
    def return_complete_dict(self):
        list_of_citation_objects = []
        pdf_text = self.__get_pdf_text__()
        citation_regex = self.__get_citation_regex__()
        url_regex = self.__get_url_regex__()
        doi_regex = self.__get_doi_regex__()
        citation_data = re.findall(citation_regex, pdf_text)
        list_of_urls = re.findall(url_regex, pdf_text)
        list_of_dois = re.findall(doi_regex, pdf_text)
        for citation in citation_data:
            list_of_citation_objects.append(CitationObj(citation[1], citation[0], citation[2]))
        citation_dict = {"Citations": list_of_citation_objects,
                         "URLS": list_of_urls,
                         "DOIS": list_of_dois}
        return citation_dict

    # Returns a array of all matches to the url regex if present
    def return_url_array(self):
        pdf_text = self.__get_pdf_text__()
        url_regex = self.__get_url_regex__()
        return re.findall(url_regex, pdf_text)

    # Returns a array of all matches to the doi regex if present
    def return_doi_array(self):
        pdf_text = self.__get_pdf_text__()
        doi_regex = self.__get_doi_regex__()
        return re.findall(doi_regex, pdf_text)

    # Returns a array of all matches to the url regex if present
    def is_pdf(self):
        try:
            textract.process(self.filePath).decode("utf-8")
            return True
        except:
            return False

    # Clears the analyzed files from the analyzedFiles list
    def clear_analyzed_files(self):
        self.analyzedFiles = []

    # Changes the file the loader is extracting info from
    def change_file(self, new_file_path):
        self.filePath = new_file_path

    # Extracts all the text from the pdf while removing superfluous/unmatched space characters
    def __get_pdf_text__(self):
        text = textract.process(self.filePath).decode("utf-8")
        text = text.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '  ')
        return text

    # Gets the regex from the user defined file that extracts citations
    def __get_citation_regex__(self):
        with open(self.regexPath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            regex_dict = json.load(f)
        return re.compile(regex_dict.get("Citation"), re.MULTILINE)

    # Gets the regex from the user defined file that extracts urls
    def __get_url_regex__(self):
        with open(self.regexPath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            regex_dict = json.load(f)
        return re.compile(regex_dict.get("URL"))

    # Gets the regex from the user defined file that extracts DOI's
    def __get_doi_regex__(self):
        with open(self.regexPath, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            regex_dict = json.load(f)
        return re.compile(regex_dict.get("DOI"))

    # Determines if the file has already been analyzed and returns a boolean to that effect
    def __has_file_been_read__(self):
        if len(self.analyzedFiles) > 0:
            for file in self.analyzedFiles:
                if self.filePath == file:
                    return False
        return True
```

Any and all help is appreciated, as I'm somewhat bashing my head against a wall trying to get things to work.

Comment: Include few first bytes of the original file causing problems. It doesn't looks like a valid utf-8 encoded text.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. 

I'm not sure it's any one specific pdf file causing issues, it's any - I've tried multiple files from the test dataset the original developer had, and some that I had on my PC. 

Though to rule it out, and at the risk of sounding like an idiot (sorry, not had to do this before) - how exactly do I find the bytes of the file to send?

Comment: PDF documents are not utf-8 encoded. It looks like you are using `CitationLoaderTxt` to process PDF files while you have `CitationLoaderPDF` for that.

Comment: Oh, thank you. It is my current understanding of the code that the CitationLoaderPDF mines PDF files to text files before processing. If PDF files are not utf encoded, I am not sure why the original developer tried to decode the pdf files with  "textract.process(self.filePath).decode("utf-8")". I will try to play around with this and see if it fixes it, though with initial tinkering I am not getting another error but with 'charmap' codec over utf8